Startup based on my own side project open-sourced through my employer
I work at a FAANG-size company (moonlighting friendly in theory) and have a side project that I've built mostly in my free time, a bit during work hours, and had it recently approved by the legal department for open-sourcing and it's now available in public on GitHub with an MIT license for everything.
Since the MIT license allows anyone to do whatever they want with the project, including commercial use and creating derivatives, I'm tempted now to create a startup based on the project - basically fork it and work in private on it, extending and improving it a lot (make it worth buying it compared to OSS version), then rebrand and launch it as a subscription app.
The moonlighting policy is fairly permissive, but also somewhat vague. Both my contract and current HR guidance state that any invention is mine if done outside work hours, not using their hardware AND doesn't compete with the company and harms it's business interests - the vague part, especially with a company that has it's fingers in dozens of different software. It's not needed to inform manager or HR about moonlighting, just "use your judgement if it fits the policy". WA state.
There are several concerns I have and I'm also curious if others have dealt with a similar situation and have some advice:

my fear is that even if I'm following the moonlighting policies from now on, they could later still claim ownership of my work based on the pre-OSS work. If someone else outside the company would fork the OSS repo there should be no problems given the MIT license. My hope was that starting now from a fork creates a clean slate for me, since the previous work was done in part during work hours on their PCs. Open-sourcing through my employer was the only way not to lose it completely in case I switch companies (and remain abandoned, no one cares enough about it).

the company doesn't have a stand-alone product it sells similar to my app, but it does have a module part of a much larger product. That product is far from being the money-maker for the company (it's seen as a cost center). People are certainly not buying the whole product because of that module, it's a nice thing to have. There are several other companies that do sell stand-alone apps similar to mine though, there is a market for it. I assume that module is enough to argue that my app is a direct competitor if one really wants to though.


Given this, feels like safest would be to quit my job before even starting to work on this, but of course I'd like to avoid that, with the startup maybe not working out - concern 1) could also mean this wouldn't actually help. Switching first to another company is another option, but seems others have even worse or no moonlighting and again concern 1). Last option, work on it while employed and hope I won't get sued. Maybe quit around the time I'm close to be done with a v1 and start marketing to reduce risk a bit.
As for the company itself, I'm not seeking funding and don't see it getting to some multi-million/y business, at best enough to make a full-time job out of it. Maybe that's enough to not make it worth suing. I will consult with an attorney too, wanted to check first with other entrepreneurs in case it's completely hopeless.

All valid fears... I don't think anyone can honestly answer this as it depends on who you are working for. I would ask an attorney... And depending on his answer ask your boss/companies legal team. I don't know that we can answer this.

It will help if your target customers are different then your employers target customers.

The fact that the license permitage does not necessarily mean that your contract with your employer, or your employer's policies, permit it while you are their employee. You need to negotiate those with them.

Consult a lawyer if you want to get an accurate answer. A lawyer will explain everything to you (perhaps, for a small fee ?). But, that is likely much better than asking random people on the internet.

The fact that it's MIT-licensed doesn't stop it failing the duck test - the basis of your startup was built on their time and resources, and if you were involved in any way in the decision to open-source it they could argue that you chose not to disclose an obvious conflict of interest. This is a long way into "get a lawyer" territory.

I've done almost the exact same thing: use a MIT license based project that I developed at a company as a basis for my own project. See: https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/158965/108451 and continued working for the company for over a year. Now I'm working full time for my own company and it is our main product. In my case nobody cared or mentioned it and it worked out fine. MIT gives you the right in principle to use the code. The fact that you worked on the project before shouldn't be relevant if you stick to using the open sourced code.

You mention "side project" and "moonlighting", but also, "in part during work hours on their PCs."  Those ideas don't align well.  You may have already created a partial ownership for the company by those actions. The company may have a right to a percentage of the software or your proceeds for your work because of that.
Thee MIT license may free others from an obligation to your employer, but may not protect you.  You did violate the company's policy and we can't say for sure what that means for you.  You really need a lawyer.

This really is a matter of company policy. There can certainly be an appearance of conflict of interest, if you are selling your services to the same people the company is selling to, or if there is any question about whether the work you are doing on company time is for your own benefit rather than theirs. If the company permits it at all, there will be specific rules to set boundaries around this.
In the US, note that your contract usually says that all intellectual property you develop while employed by the company, even on your own time, belongs to the company unless they say otherwise. so this really is a matter of what they will and will not permit.
Ask your manager.

I'm not a lawyer, I would just give a shot. I've told multi million $$ companies who threatened me with court cases to bug off and do whatever they want.
It's business. In grey areas and especially if you're an entrepreneur it's reasonably common to just go for it and handle whatever eventuates as it arises. Otherwise many things would never have gotten off the ground at all that we use all the time these days. This goes back well before computers were invented.
If anything hits the fan you can deal with it then. But it all comes down to cost. Most large companies won't want their names dragged through courts for trifles. And if you have a super lucrative product, your company can afford to pay them to bug off.

I would stop working on the project on company hardware. Silicon Valley devoted an entire season to the reason that’s a bad idea.
